# Remote Desktop possible using computer name but not IP address

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop

From a computer on a network, I can remote desktop to another computer on the same network using the computer name but not the IP address.

What could be the problem with using the IP address? Is it a networking issue?

I would have thought that if I can connect using the computer name then there is a route to that computer.

[image]

Comment: Using IP address works here and has worked any time I have used it. Are you sure the IP address is correct?  How did you enter it (edit your post to add a screen shot)?   What error did you (add another screen shot to your post)?

Comment: What is the result – the error message if any – that you get when connecting via IP address?

Comment: Are you using a PKI ? RDP'ing by IP will invalidate certificates.

Comment: It is just the standard error you get with RDP, see my edit.

Comment: Can you verify with `Resolve-DnsName <host> | fl` or at least with `nslookup` that the name has exactly the address you're trying to reach, and no other addresses? (Keep in mind "foo" and "foo.ad.example.com" might not be the same, and it also might be resolved through other means than DNS, so powershell's Resolve-DnsName would be preferred over nslookup, despite the name.)

Comment: Try mapping the server:   net use z: \\ipaddress\folder.   What numerical error do you get. This is just a trial to see if we can get Windows numerical error messages.

Comment: Is this a business network? If so, have you spoken with the network and system admins regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons:

1. A computer name could be associated with *multiple* IP addresses. For example, an IPv4 address and an IPv6 address would be typical.

   In a dual-stack (v4+v6) network, a connection by name will try the IPv6 address first – so if the IPv4 address is wrong or there's no route to it, nobody would notice for a long time.

   Use `Resolve-DnsName <host> | fl` in PowerShell to verify that the domain you're trying *actually* resolves to the address you have.
2. In an Active Directory environment, RDP uses Kerberos for authentication. Kerberos, a bit like TLS, authenticates also the server, not just the client – it verifies that the computer name you requested is the one you actually reached.

   In nearly all setups, however, *only* the name – not any IP addresses – is registered with Kerberos (which is again a lot like how most websites only have TLS certificates for their domain name, not for their IP address; after all, the latter is somewhat transient).

   This means that connecting via IP address (or even any name that's not registered with Kerberos as a SPN for the server) will prevent the client from completing Kerberos authentication. Usually it would fall back to NTLM (the same as in non-AD environments), but if the AD environment is properly taken care of, it will either have NTLM disabled completely *or* at least have NTLM SPN enforcement enabled (and the latter again requires the input name to match the reached name), so connections to IP addresses will not be possible.
3. Modern RDP uses TLS for its transport security and the server has a TLS certificate. In AD environments you usually don't see it (Kerberos overrides the TLS certificate check), but if Kerberos fails due to name mismatch and the client falls back to NTLM, it *will* check the server's TLS certificate.

   Said certificate, again, is usually issued for the RDP server's name only. Usually a mismatch would cause the RDP client to just pop up an "Accept this certificate" prompt, but it is quite possible that the client computer has a policy configured that *requires* the certificate verification to succeed. (Connecting to an untrusted RDP server carries more risks than e.g. SSH.)